# The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) float, Optional<Float>

Tags: java

I'm new in Java Language and I was trying to calculate a weighted average:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Float> grades = new ArrayList<Float>();
        ArrayList<Float> wheightes = new ArrayList<Float>();
        int count = 0;
        while(count < 3) {
          float grade = keyboard.nextFloat();
          grades.add(grade);
          count += 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Digite 1 para média ponderada e 2 para aritmética");
        int whichAverage = keyboard.nextInt();
        switch(whichAverage){
          case 1:
          float average = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++) {
            average += grades.get(i);
          }
          System.out.println("A média aritmética é " + average / grades.size());
          case 2:
          System.out.println("Informe os 3 pesos:");
         float weightedAverage = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            float wheight = keyboard.nextFloat();
            wheightes.add(wheight);
            weightedAverage += grades.get(i) * wheightes.get(i);
          }
          Optional<Float> sumOfWheightes = wheightes.stream().reduce((prev, next) -> prev + next);
          System.out.println("A média ponderada é " + weightedAverage / sumOfWheightes);
          default:
          System.out.println("Digite 1 ou 2");
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

I tried to do a reduce:

```
Optional<Float> sumOfWheightes = wheightes.stream().reduce((prev, next) -> prev + next);
```

Then I tried to divide a `Optional<Float>` with a float type:

```
System.out.println("A média ponderada é " + weightedAverage / sumOfWheightes);
```

The error is:

> The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) float, Optional<Float>

How can I do this division?

Comment: You have to unwrap type `Optional<Float>` to the actual value so it's a `float`. See [Optional doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error really says it all - you can't divide a `float` by an `Optioanl<Float>`, you need to convert it to a `float` first. E.g., by using `orElse`:

```
float sumOfWheightes =
    wheightes.stream().reduce((prev, next) -> prev + next).orElse(1.0f);
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot. Just one thing: it's not necessary anymore use Optional<Float>, the correct in this code is to declare as float. My line now it's:

```Float sumOfWheightes = wheightes.stream().reduce((prev, next) -> prev + next).orElse(1.0f);```

Comment: @LuizPortela Oops! Good catch! With the added `orElse` clause, `sumOfWeights is now a `flaot`. See my edited answer.